# Is there a way to sort groupBy keys in rx-java/kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

Here's an example:

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOf("4444", "22", "333", "1", "55555"))
    .groupBy { it.hashCode() }
    .subscribe { group ->
        group.toList().subscribe { list -> println("${group.key} $list") }
    }
```

output:

```
1600 [22]
49 [1]
50643 [333]
50578165 [55555]
1600768 [4444]
```

How to sort the keys in ascending/descending order or using a custom sort comparator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solution is to use `sorted` function with custom `Comparator`:

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOf("4444", "22", "333", "1", "55555"))
        .groupBy { it.hashCode() }
        .sorted { o1, o2 ->
            o1.key?.minus(o2.key ?: 0) ?: 0
        }
        .subscribe { group ->
            group.toList().subscribe { list -> println("${group.key} $list") }
        }
```

Output:

```
49 [1]
1600 [22]
50643 [333]
1600768 [4444]
50578165 [55555]
```